Why is Centripetal force effect loss a delayed process?
I have heard from senior students that the effect of centrifugal force is not gone immediately when the force is removed. So when I am whirling a stone, the moment i release the stone is not going to be the moment when the centrifugal force actually stops acting on the stone. For some reason I don't understand, the force will disappear only after some time (very small though). Why does this happen?

Is this valid or was that a misconception? I mean, can I understand it's validity with Newton's Laws? Or is Newton's Laws insufficient to make it valid?  That is, is there any deeper principle I don't know?

I don't know if this is very off topic or meaningless, but what disturbs me about this is that force is behaving like particles in this property: it takes some time to disappear. Just like a particle cannot immediately invert its direction by any angle which would look like an infinite acceleration (something impossible in the universe), the real life force is also not disappearing immediately.



I know this has been covered here somewhere. The speed of sound in a material determines how fast "information" gets from one place to another.  When the string snaps, this creates a wave pulse that will travel down the length of the string. Only once this pulse hits the end of the string (where position of the stone) does the stone stop feeling the inward centripetal force. This pulse take a finite amount of time due to the finite speed of waves in the string.

This video shows the effect. There is both a theoretical explanation and some really wonderful slow-motion experiments of the effect.

I can't seem to find a duplicate question here, so I guess I'll post an answer. Perhaps someone can find a duplicate later on.

The speed of sound (i.e., long wavelength speed of waves) in a material determines how fast "information" gets from one place to another. When the string snaps, this creates a wave pulse that will travel down the length of the string. Only once this pulse hits the end of the string (where position of the stone) does the stone stop feeling the inward centripetal force.  This pulse takes a non-zero amount of time due to the finite speed of waves in the string.
It's easiest to understand this by replacing the string with a slinky and understanding how the "tension" in the slinky is cause by the different coils in the slinky pulling on each neighboring coil. If one coil goes slack, that causes the next coil to go slack, which causes the next coil to go slack, etc., all the way down the slinky. This clearly takes a finite amount of time, as the coils can't all go slack all at once (if nothing else, this violates principles of special relativity!).
This video shows the effect. There is both a theoretical explanation and some really wonderful slow-motion experiments of the effect.

Thank that's an awesome visual. Even if I can't do it mathematically, that is the ultimate visual
